# Menu Icon won't show after rezise

Tags: html, css

Basically I wanted to create a media query which would make my nav bar disappear and change into a menu icon... however it still won't show. Does anyone have a solution? Here's my code:

```
<header>
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <nav> 
    <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="current">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Latest Videos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

my CSS:

```css
nav {
  float: right;
  padding: 35px 20px 20px 0px;
}
#menu-icon{
  display: hidden;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url(http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/icon.png) center;
}
a:hover#menu-icon {
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;   
}
ul {
  list-style: none; 
}
nav ul li {
  font-size: 25px; 
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
}
.current {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

and finally my media query:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 478) {
  body {
    position: absolute; 
  } 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 478) {
  header {
    position: absolute; 
  }
  #menu-icon {
    display: inline-block;  
  }
  nav ul, nav:active ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #405580;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    right: 20px;
    top: 60px;
    width: 50%;
    border-radius: 2px 0 2px 2px;
  }
  nav li {
    text-align: center;
    width:: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0;  
  }
  nav:hover ul {
    display: block; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#syntax), looks like you need to add the `px` after `478`:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 478px) {
  body {
    position: absolute; 
  } 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 478px) {
```

Comment: added px after 478 and still nothing

Comment: @AnishMurthy Just a thought. Are you sure both are `max-width`?

Comment: @AnishMurthy Is it `max-width` and `min-width`?

Comment: im trying to make the icon show on a phone basically.

Comment: @AnishMurthy I checked using phone and RWD view.

Comment: @AnishMurthy Chrome - F12, click on the small mobile icon on the left top.

Comment: @AnishMurthy Firefox - [Responsive Design View](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View) - There's a whole lot to explore! `:)`

Comment: menu icon still isn't showing up... however when I hover over the top right section I see my drop down... how do I get the icon to show?

Comment: @AnishMurthy Can you show me a snippet or fiddle that has this issue? http://jsbin.com will be perfect for this use-case.

Answer (score 0):

First off `display: hidden;` *isnt* a thing. You are looking for `display:none`.

Additionally you can use `visibility: hidden;` *or* `visibility: visible;`

If an object is set to display:none. And then you want to reveal it again at a specific screen width. You need to change the display value of that object in your media query.

`display:block;` or `display:inline-block;` *or even in some cases* `display:inline;`

**For example:**

```
#menu-icon{
  display: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url(http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/icon.png) center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 478px) {
#menu-icon{
  display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: This helped hide my nav bar... but the icon still isn't appearing. Thoughts?